# Grafana - Get paginated list of the Alert Rules

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

Does anybody know if there is a way to get a paginated list of the Alert Rules via the Grafana API. Specifically for Grafana versions 7.5.17 and 9.3.X

I found this endpoint for the version 9.3

```
/api/ruler/grafana/api/v1/rules
```

But this API marked as unstable and there is no pagination. Pagination is very important in my case. Maybe there is another way to get the Alert rules?

Comment: I don't believe paging is available. Also, new Alerting API marked `unstable` as a whole. You could use [old version of api](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.5/http_api/alerting/#get-alerts) on both instances - for 7.5 it would be current version ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the alert rules using this endpoint, in JSON format.`GET /api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules`

Comment: This endpoint returns "message": "Not found". 
On the Grafana forum they said that the Provisioning API is available only since version 9.4